How to use SQL Server's Always Encrypt feature in DBeaver?
I want to be able to work with SQL Server's Always Encrypted fields in DBeaver.
I have successfully used the Always Encrypted feature in SSMS and have enabled the Memory Protection Extensions, allowing queries that use Transact-SQL operators supported inside secure enclaves. So, in terms of configuration, it should be successful.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-enclaves-query-columns?view=sql-server-ver16
However, I don't know where to import the keys in DBeaver or how to achieve the functionality available in SSMS.
Does DBeaver support operations on SQL Server's Always Encrypted fields?
I hope to achieve the same functionality in DBeaver as in SSMS.

Which edition of DBeaver are you using? I expect that DBeaver community edition would not be able to do this since it lacks the Preferences > General  > Security > Certificates Trust Store panel that would be needed to import your CEK.

I have updated DBeaver to the latest version 24.0.3.202404211624.

Try to edit the driver's parameters:

KeyStoreAuthentication
KeyStorePrincipalId
KeyStoreSecret
ColumnEncryption=Enabled
TrustServerCertificate=Yes

For me, since I use a Windows Certificate, I only set ColumnEncryption=Enabled and TrustServerCertificate=Yes.
